# seeking Best practice advice related to managing iBeacon localnotifications

Tags: ios7, uilocalnotification, uistoryboardsegue, ibeacon

I have a storyboard app with loads of (~45) uiviewControllers.  Whether in background or foreground, when a beacon triggers a uilocalnotification and the user accepts it, I want to "push/segue" to the UIViewController associated with that beacon trigger.  Simple enough.  Depending on the beacon, I have approx 10 different VCs that I would segue to.

The question I have is this.  The user could literally be sitting at any one of my 45 UIViewCtrlers when the beacon triggers the notification so every one of my UIViewControllers has to have something similar to the below, (along with the code block for the selector), in order to act upon the notification and push/segue to another viewcontroller.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(showFoodMenuViewNow)
                                             name:@"showfoodmenu" object:nil];
```

This is going to literally riddle my storyboard with more inter-VC push/segue connections than you could shake a stick at.  Very messy.  Is there some way to eliminate all the visual storyboard segues or somehow introduce a single 'vector viewcontroller' that all the views segue to.  That VC would then evaluate the localnotification and push to the associated VC.

What is the recommended best practice for managing this?

Hope I'm making sense.

UPDATE:

I've switched paths now, trying to access the UINavigationController directly from my appDelegate.  I'm using the following code to do that and, although my nc is not nil, no view is pushed...

Why would this code not push the desired viewcontroller?

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
nm_vcFoodMenu *fm = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"foodmenu"];
UINavigationController *nc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNavController"];
if (nc == nil){
    NSLog(@"nc is nil");
} else {
    NSLog(@"nc is not nil so trying to push to foodmenu");
    [nc pushViewController:(nm_vcFoodMenu *)fm  animated:YES];
}
```

This is a depiction of my storyboard and the various moving parts.  Hoping this will help you help me!
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not claim to have a good solution for this, but below is what I do for what it's worth.  I also would like to hear if anybody has a better solution.

1. I manage iBeacon transitions programatically in my AppDelegate without any setup in the storyboard.
2. I take special care that two iBeacons don't cause two transitions too closely in time to eachother (a minimum of a few seconds must have passed since the last transition, otherwise I delay the transition with a timer or suppress it.)
3. Managing the stack in the navigation controller is a real pain.  Only in specific cases where I know I want the user to be able to go back do I do a `[navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES]`.  And in some cases I end up suppressing the back button in my `ViewController`s with `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

Admittedly, all of this is really messy.  But given the dynamic nature of how iBeacon-based transitions can happen, I think it is often hard to set up all the combinations ahead of time.

Comment: David, I too have my appdelegate as the ibeacon/notification delegate and tried to do what you describe but I was unable to segue in code without involving a corresponding segue in the storyboard.  Can you provide a snippet of a segue from appDelegate(uilocalnotification delegate) to a specified UIViewController?  As I mention above, some of my segues are of a custom type in order to support the SWRevealViewController mechanics.  (it is open source module that provides a side-slide-out menu).  All of my uilocalNotifications need to trigger a segue to one of these types of uiviewcontrollers.

Comment: Yes, there is actually a snippet above -- it's super simple.  I just keep a reference to the NavigationController in my AppDelegate, then call: [navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES]

Comment: I tried the above but since I am using storyboard, none of the viewcontrollers I want to "jump" to exist yet.  I am attempting to get a handle on the viewcontroller I want to goto...
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
nm_vcMenu *fm = [[UIStoryboard   storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"foodmenu"];
UINavigationController* nc = self.window.rootViewController.navigationController;
[nc pushViewController:fm animated:NO];  // I get no result - any ideas?

Comment: Check that all the objects your created are not nil. A common issue with that, it the nil UINavigationController, so no push.

Comment: Try putting your transition inside as block like this:[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ ... }];

Comment: Ok, so my UINavigationController is indeed nil... Seems the key is to figure out how to get pointer to the UINavigationController from within my appDelegate.  Seems the code I have above should work?

Comment: @phil, one way to do this is to add a property to your AppDelegate for the NavigationController, and then set it from your initial ViewController.  Like this: SHAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SHAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; appDelegate.navigationController = self.navigationController;

Comment: Tried that, thanks, David.  No joy though.  I tried it from the initial view controller.  See my update in the main question - I've provided a graphic of my storyboard.

Comment: OK, can you add a snippet to the viewDidLoad method of the "Main Home PageVC" that gets the NavigationController (it should not be nil here!) and sets it on the appDelegate.

Comment: @davidgyoung - trying now!

Comment: @davidgyoung - genious, simply genious.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In our project, we create dedicated singleton that plays as iBeacon delegate, and present our notification interface over top view controller,  so all logic contains in one place and no need to make modification in other view controllers.

Comment: Thanks, sage.  So does that mean that the singleton would need to simply get a handle on the top viewcontroller and the segues, specific to each notification, would exist in the storyboard leading from the singleton to each notification targetview.  Or would the segues need to originate from the top viewcontroller?  My only other concern is that I'm also using the SWRevealViewControler open source interface to provide a slider menu that pans from the side.  Do you think that would throw a wrench into the works at all?

Comment: Here is an unanswered question on this topic that I posted a few days back...  http://stackoverflow.com/q/21884926/615518